# Inexplicable High Ping on Verizon Fios

Tags: networking, ping

Suddenly today YouTube videos wouldn't load. Before I was able to watch 1080p60fps videos no problem on my OnePlus One as well as my PC, now it doesn't even play 144p well. I tried several speedtests, however they overall seemed fine. Then trying to play CSGO, where before I got 20ms Ping everytime, I had 100ms.

Running a ping test to google.com gives this.

```
Pinging google.com [173.194.208.113] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.194.208.113: bytes=32 time=209ms TTL=48
Reply from 173.194.208.113: bytes=32 time=195ms TTL=48
Reply from 173.194.208.113: bytes=32 time=209ms TTL=48
Reply from 173.194.208.113: bytes=32 time=200ms TTL=48
```

Clearly something is wrong here.

Running a Ping test to my router from my Computer over Ethernet yields the expected result:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

So the Issue isn't my Computer. Running a tracert to google and I get this:

```
Tracing route to google.com [173.194.208.100] over a maximum of 30 hops:
1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
2     7 ms     7 ms     6 ms  lo0-100.NYCMNY-VFTTP-320.verizon-gni.net [72.69.227.1]
3     7 ms     6 ms     9 ms  B3320.NYCMNY-LCR-21.verizon-gni.net [100.41.212.129]
4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
5    44 ms    43 ms    48 ms  0.ae13.GW13.NYC1.ALTER.NET [140.222.234.193]
6    40 ms    47 ms    43 ms  google-gw.customer.alter.net [204.148.18.206]
7     *      142 ms   149 ms  209.85.247.7
8    47 ms    52 ms    48 ms  216.239.40.227
9     *      208 ms     *     108.170.236.243
10   210 ms     *        *     216.239.48.160
11   195 ms     *      208 ms  216.239.49.79
12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
13   203 ms   199 ms   215 ms  ql-in-f100.1e100.net [173.194.208.100]
```

Running Speedtests on [beta.speedtest.net](http://beta.speedtest.net/) gives widely differnet results, from 3Mpbs Upload and 140ms Ping to 25 Mpbs and 9ms (I pay for 25/25).
Pingtest.net gives me results generally like [this](http://www.pingtest.net/result/151835829.png), sometimes it gives me 49ms.

I have tried changing the DNS to google, no difference. I have reset and rebooted everything possible.

What is the issue here?

Comment: If you're on windows, pathping is handy in situations like this

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a verizon router? If so did you try to restart it? if this doesnt help you should probably call verizon to see whats up.

I find it strange that your ping increases from verizon and forward. Yes there could be a bit of a delay but not 200ms.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you run into problems at the 9th hop in your trace.  I can't tell you what carrier is responsible for that hop, but it is possible that it is having issues or is getting attacked.  Looks like there may be some level of packet loss as well, the only way to really tell is to use a tool called MTR (I don't know if there is or what the Windows equivalent is). Although determining that node to being the problem or not, it won't really help your situation.

Options:

Get a VPN service for the time being.  A lot of times VPN traffic will take a different route and that way you can avoid that bad node altogether.

Escalate the issue with Verizon.  From an ISP standpoint, they are customers to transit carriers, when there were issues with a transit carrier that was just a sub carrier to our primary carrier, we had to engage our carrier to escalate the issue with their sub carrier.  At the consumer level, I don't know how far this will get you, but if enough people are calling about it, your ISP should take action to get a case open with that carrier.

More reconaissance:

To get a better idea of your issue, do a traceroute (or pathping  or MTR) to the sites you are having trouble with, see if it takes the same path to get there (or relatively same path).  Also, the speed test you conducted usually tries to find the closest server which could be before that problematic node, try running a speed test to a server that is slightly further away.

Best of luck!

Comment: `108.170.236.243` belongs to google.